# Not visible DotNetNuke implementation module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I download [DNNTaskManager Module](https://dnntaskmanager.codeplex.com/)  and upload the source zip file to create a module,when I drug task manager module from Add New Module menu I don's see any module implementation :

[image]

Any idea why I cant see the content(i.e. the controls) of TaskManager module or maybe I missing something in settings?

P.S If I davelope my own module and use it in DNN it's works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael,

Make your page in **Edit Mode** and click on Module's Pen Icon (Beside Settings Icon) to enter new task. It will redirect you to Task entry form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upload the instal version, not the source version. The install version has the .dll file and the ascx.